# .htaccess "?" Sign in file names trouble

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, quote

There are static html files called `blahblah.html?somestring`. I'm always get 404 error.
When I try `blahblah.html%3fsomething` - it semi-works (shows html source as text), but ` need URLs to be exactly with question sign.

How to make Apache show to this files with exact URL containing "?".

I tried to **rename** file to "blahblah.html-somestring" **+ rule in .htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*).html\?(.*)$ /$1.html-$2 [NE]
```

it **doesn't help**

**THIS HELPED ME:
I renamed all files to blahblah.html-somestring.html + added this to .htaccess:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^[^.]+\.html/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}-%{QUERY_STRING}.html? [L,NC]
```

Comment: The `?` is a special character when used inside URLs. The "semi-works" is in fact the expected behavior.

Comment: `blahblah.html?somestring` means: file = `blahblah.html`; query string = `somestring`

Comment: Yeah, i know... But i'm trying to change this expected behavior. I tried to rename file to blahblah.html-somestring + RewriteRule ^/(.*).html\?(.*)$ /$1.html-$2 [NE] - it doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^[^.]+\.html/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}-%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,NC,R]
```

This will rewrite `blahblah.html?somestring` to `blahblah.html-somestring`. However how the content will be served from `blahblah.html-somestring`, you will have to figure out.

Comment: WOW!! The first thing that really works! But **still** these files are shown like just text files (I see the html source), but i suppose it's server preferences

Comment: Just add `T` flag, e.g. `T=text/html` : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_t

Answer (score 0):

Actually I can see two problems here:

#### 1) You want to use the ? character as part of file names

I cannot see a plain solution of this problem. The question mark is part of the HTTP protocol and you can rewrite URLs but the desired solution is not possible with these tools. If you can live with the %3f approach this will be the most simple way to solve this.

#### 2) You want to set correct MIME types beside from file suffixes

Apache detects the correct MIME type (e.g. text/html) depending on a files name. If the file is ending to .htm or .html Apache delivers the content with the MIME type text/html. 
As your file names do not end with the expected suffixes and regular expression do work for the MIME table the only way to make this working is some regex within the mod_rewrite module. Here you can detect the suffix in the middle of the filename and are able to set the MIME type:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+\.html.*)$ $1 [T=text/html]
```

#### Overall solution:

You can solve #1 and #2 with a simple Web application, checking the origin request string and delivering the matching file (as well as setting the correct MIME type). You can do such things for example with PHP.